# Xdebug 3 docker mac PhpStorm broken pipe

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I see `There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 11: Broken pipe.` in the xdebug.log and cannot see why. Have gone around in circles for days trying all sorts of stuff. What am I doing wrong?

- Xdebug 3.0.3,
- PhpStorm 2020.3.3,
- Mac OS X latest,
- Safari browser

```
[17] Log opened at 2021-03-24 02:49:43.184877
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.18.0.1:9003.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.18.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)
[17] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/manawatech/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17" idekey="19213"><engine version="3.0.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[17] [Step Debug] WARN: 2021-03-24 02:49:43.851075: There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 11: Broken pipe.
[17] Log closed at 2021-03-24 02:49:43.851495
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "9003:9003"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/manawatech
    extra_hosts: # <-- this is required for ray
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" # <-- this is required for ray
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
```

docker/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8-apache-buster
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y geoip-bin geoip-database libgeoip-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install redis apcu xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd zip \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis apcu xdebug pdo pdo_mysql gd zip
# from https://github.com/nezhar/php-docker-ssl/blob/master/Dockerfile
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -subj "/C=AT/ST=Vienna/L=Vienna/O=Security/OU=Development/CN=manawatech.local"
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf \
    && a2enmod rewrite ssl expires headers
COPY docker/php/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
COPY docker/php/98-production.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY docker/php/99-development.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 9003
```

/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-development.ini

```ini
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.force_display_errors=1
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Comment: Why do you need this `- "9003:9003"` line in your docker-compose.yml file? Same with `EXPOSE 9003` in Dockerfile. What that is for? If this is for Xdebug .. then you are wrong and this is not how it works. Just in case: check the Xdebug docs -- it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. With your current setup Docker uses that port for own needs (will forward incoming requests from host into the container) hence your IDE/Editor is unable to listen for incoming Xdebug requests. Get rid of them/comment out and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I do that, I see `web    | [Wed Mar 24 20:40:43.831600 2021] [php:notice] [pid 18] [client 172.18.0.1:62128] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 172.18.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Comment: I'm not a Docker expert in any way .. I may only say what I've said already: 1) you do not need to expose Xdebug port in your Docker as its Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. If you expose it then it's Docker that listens on that port and not your IDE. You can check that with `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` or similar comment -- see what process listens 9003 -- it should be your PhpStorm/VSCode (or whatever you are using there) -- when it listens for connections of course (e.g. green "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm).

Comment: 2) `extra_hosts: # <-- this is required for ray- "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` -- this is more for a Linux (where Docker has no out of the box support for `host.docker.inetrnal`) -- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-772844305. **Maybe** it is not needed on your Mac or needed for your image (cannot say what it does).

Comment: 3) You will not see "we need to expose Xdebug port in our Docker config" in any manuals. So the problem has to be elsewhere. https://learnxdebug.com/ ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw , https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/ ,  https://marcuschristiansen.medium.com/setup-xdebug-in-laravel-8-like-a-boss-ea7582ce01ce , https://vimeo.com/433218463 , https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#configuring-xdebug-docker

Comment: FWIW, the log shows that Xdebug created a connection and sent data over it. The remote (IDE) side closed the connection. When that happens Xdebug tries to send the `stopping` response, which it can't because the connection is closed. That results in the warning "can't send 179 bytes".